# Detect that the Intellisense tooltip didn't show up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, autohotkey

I am using AutoHotkey to display the intellisense tooltip by using Ctrl+Space. When no more members can be listed,  Ctrl+Space doesn't display the tooltip anymore and when that happen, I want to be able to detect it and stop my script.

I thought about using an offset of the caret position to detect a pixel color matching with the wrench icon color, but unfortunately it appears that AutoHotkey can't give the caret position coming from visual studio. I also tried using image and pixel search, without success :

Using this image  [image] and this code

```
ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, C:\Users\slariviere\Pictures\wrench.jpg
```

[image]

I also tried looking for difference with the spy window. The first image shows a class when my mouse was on VS background.

[image]

When my mouse hover on the Intellisense tooltip, I don't have a class, could I leverage this ?
[image]

Is there any other AutoHotkey functionality I could use ?
Or is there any other way to detect for remaining class Properties in visual studio?

Comment: From what I have seen, the Intellisense tooltip is the only thing that doesn't have a a class name in VS. I could I use that to my advantage ?

Comment: How could I use that to my advantage ? ***

Comment: A few ideas: 1) Play around with [WinGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm) and [ControlGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm), e.g. `WinGet, list, ControlList`, or maybe some other command option. For example, the number of controls before and after IntelliSense may give you what you need. 2) A long shot, but maybe [WinGetText](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetText.htm) reveals the existence of the tooltip. 3) I don't see why `ImageSearch`for the wrench symbol shouldn't work. Can you provide the code you came up with?

Comment: Thanks @MCL for these ideas, I'll try them. As for the image search, I erased my code but it was something like this : `ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, C:\Users\slariviere\Pictures\wrench.jpg` but my variables where always empty when trying to display them with MsgBox

Comment: You can always edit your question and add further information. I think it would be helpful to others if you provided the code that didn't work directly in your question (and also every other useful info like the tooltip not having a ClassNN etc.), and not just in the comments. To your code: Try saving the wrench symbol in a lossless format (e.g. BMP/PNG), this will increase the chances of ImageSearch finding it. Also, try to crop it as much as possible, so the (white) border is as small as possible.

Comment: What is the window text about? *"Find Symbol Results - 2 matches found"* Does that correspond to the IntelliSense function?

Comment: @MCL This is unrelated to Intellisense, the text is about another functionality of VS, in this case I apparently did a "Find all references" prior to testing AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCL solution worked for me :

> Try saving the wrench symbol in a lossless format (e.g. BMP/PNG),
>   this will increase the chances of ImageSearch finding it. Also, try to
>   crop it as much as possible, so the (white) border is as small as
>   possible.

I saved the file as a PNG and the image I used was [image] to differentiate between the tooltip and the other places this image is used.